# Browser displayed samesite warning about facebook pixel

Tags: facebook, cookies, pixel, facebook-pixel, samesite

Facebook pixel make cookie and this cookie does not allow `samesite=none`
How can I handle this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What _is_ there to handle? You got a _warning_ here only. Before this becomes an actual issue, Facebook will likely update their SDK to set the correct attribute.

Comment: Did you know facebook milestone about samesite policy

@misorude

Comment: I doubt they’d publish any milestone for something so minor.